# Win10 Creators update erased my start menu

Tags: windows-10

I just updated windows 10 and now my start menu is gone.. completely.. it is now looking just like a generic start menu they put on new systems.

How can I restore my old layout? I didn't know this would happen so I didn't screenshot it first. This is really a disaster because trying to recreate it manually will take a very long time. I had at least 50 programs and utilities there nicely organized. I assume it is creators update - it addded a people taskbar buton.

My users folder seem fairly unaffected. So it didn't erase my user profile or anything like that.

Comment: What have you lost? The changes you had made on the start menu (Windows 10 apps, installed software...)?

Comment: yes, I had many groups of programs arranged.. maybe 50 in total. So it's a lot of work to try to reconstruct it

Comment: In before someone else suggest system restore.

Comment: System restore can uncreatorify my windows? At least until I install updates again?

Comment: Personally, I don't use the start menu. But I believe it will be quicker to re-arrange everything than having it restored to previous state...

Comment: yeah I was thinking to do that (restore) over a lunch break or something but I'm not totally convinced that it would work - or if it did that it might not cause other unforseen problems. Pity MS pulls stuff like this, I'm thinking it happens to everyone - not just me.. so they can highlight their new "amazing" apps like Paint3D